# python imprt own function in html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscript, pyodide

knowing that with `<py-config>` and `<py-script>` can execute python code in html

---

However, importing own function facing error
`(PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'bread'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'bread'. See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information.`

- html script

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <b><p>title <u><label id="AAA"></label></u> </p></b>
    <br>
  
    <py-config>

      packages = ["bread"]
    </py-config>


    <py-script>
        import bread.py
        bread.fun_1()

    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- own python script "bread.py"

```
def fun_1():
    print("this is bread")
```

[(pic) the result screenshot for above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipnqj.png)

---

if I import my own function in another .py script is working, but do the same thing into html not works
[(pic) the result that import my own function in another .py script is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bPms.png)

I read through the link system recommend  [link](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel), and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101508/call-python-function-using-html) but I can't find out the solution myself, that I need a hand for this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that PyScript thinks you want to import a third-party package.

To import your custom modules, use `[[fetch]]` in your `<py-config>` and replace `packages` with `files`.

```
<py-config>
  [[fetch]]
  files = ["./bread.py"]
</py-config>
```